# Android Kotlin Application crashing with Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) when running in real device

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, android-emulator, layout-inflater

My application is crashing after return in OncreateView of Fragment. The stack trace I get is:

```
D/MenuAtividadesFragment: onCreate: Cheguei no onCreate

D/MenuAtividadesFragment: onCreateView: Cheguei no On createView

I/zygote: Starting a blocking GC NativeAllocBlocking

D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap

I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)

D/MenuAtividadesFragment: onViewCreated: Cheguei em On View Created

I/Choreographer: Skipped 1195 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

D/skia: external/skia/include/core/SkBitmap.h:282: fatal error: "sk_throw"

A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 11765 (.aplicativo_rdo), pid 11765 (.aplicativo_rdo)

Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:51879', transport: 'socket'
```

It returns fatal signal 6 but currently  I am only inflating the view.

```
package com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.fragment

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs
import com.eim.rdoApplication.R
import com.eim.rdoApplication.data.model.entity.ActivityEntity
import com.eim.rdoApplication.data.model.entity.InstallationReportEntity
import com.eim.rdoApplication.data.model.openWeatherApi.CurrentLocationInformation
import com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.viewModel.DepartmentsMenuViewModel
import com.eim.rdoApplication.utils.GPSUtilsKotlin
import com.eim.rdoApplication.utils.Resource
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext


private const val TAG = "MenuAtividadesFragment"
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment:Fragment(), CoroutineScope, TryAgainNetworkListener {

    private val navController by lazy {
        findNavController()
    }
    lateinit var loadingImageView: ImageView
    lateinit var loadingBg: ImageView
    lateinit var autoCompleteTextView: AutoCompleteTextView
    lateinit var reportTitleTextView:TextView
    lateinit var rootView: View
    private val args: HomeFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    private val departmentsMenuViewModel:DepartmentsMenuViewModel by viewModels()
    lateinit var dialogFragment: NetworkErrorFragment
    private var job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + job

    private var installationsReports: List<InstallationReportEntity>?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        departmentsMenuViewModel.installationReportId = args.installationReportId
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Cheguei no onCreate")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: Cheguei no On createView")
                rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_new_home_screen_updated,
                    container,
                    false
                )
//                setupReloadButton()
//                setupLoadingViews()
//                getUserInformation()
//                setupCardViews()
//                setupWeather()
                return rootView
        }
```

Only inflating the view is causing the crash, apparently.

Another interesting thing is that the fragment view can inflate when running in android virtual device(Pixel 3 API 30) but crashes in real device( Motorola G5S API 26).

I would appreciate if anyone could help me found the cause of this.

[EDITED] So Guys I installed LeakCanary to try narrow down the possible memory leak and it turns out i got closer to the cause. This is the report it gives me:

```
====================================
    HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
    ====================================
    1 APPLICATION LEAKS
    References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
    Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
    3054 bytes retained by leaking objects
    Signature: 108d5f2862bd8da48823273827314afbdcc2540
    ┬───
    │ GC Root: Local variable in native code
    │
    ├─ android.os.HandlerThread instance
    │    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader↓ is not leaking)
    │    Thread name: 'LeakCanary-Heap-Dump'
    │    ↓ HandlerThread.contextClassLoader
    ├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (InternalLeakCanary↓ is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
    │    ↓ PathClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
    ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
    │    Leaking: NO (InternalLeakCanary↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ Object[].[616]
    ├─ leakcanary.internal.InternalLeakCanary class
    │    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
    │    ↓ static InternalLeakCanary.resumedActivity
    ├─ com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.activity.MainActivity instance
    │    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
    │    mApplication instance of com.eim.rdoApplication.AppAplication
    │    mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper, not wrapping known Android context
    │    ↓ MainActivity.mFragments
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController instance
    │    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ FragmentController.mHost
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks instance
    │    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    this$0 instance of com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.activity.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    mActivity instance of com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.activity.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    mContext instance of com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.activity.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    ↓ FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.mFragmentManager
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl instance
    │    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ FragmentManagerImpl.mPrimaryNav
    ├─ androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking and Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
    │    ↓ NavHostFragment.mChildFragmentManager
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ FragmentManagerImpl.mFragmentStore
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ FragmentStore.mActive
    ├─ java.util.HashMap instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap.table
    ├─ java.util.HashMap$Node[] array
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap$Node[].[0]
    ├─ java.util.HashMap$Node instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap$Node.value
    ├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LoginFragment↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ FragmentStateManager.mFragment
    ├─ com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.fragment.login.LoginFragment instance
    │    Leaking: NO (Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
    │    componentContext instance of dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper,
    │    wrapping activity com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.activity.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    ↓ LoginFragment.loadingBg
    │                    ~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Retaining 2801 bytes in 23 objects
    │    View not part of a window view hierarchy
    │    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
D/LeakCanary: │    View.mID = R.id.imageView_loading_bg
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    mContext instance of dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper, wrapping
    │    activity com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.activity.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    ↓ AppCompatImageView.mParent
    │                         ~~~~~~~
    ╰→ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.fragment.login.LoginFragment
    ​     received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks))
    ​     Retaining 3054 bytes in 52 objects
    ​     key = 0ab7649b-62de-4b19-a9c6-7c9cf02b88a5
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 142488
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 137486
    ​     View not part of a window view hierarchy
    ​     View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    ​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    ​     mContext instance of dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper, wrapping
    ​     activity com.eim.rdoApplication.ui.activity.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
```

I got this report, but i don`t fully understand how to solve it or what I am doing wrong

Comment: Do share your xml

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out what was causing the fatal error.
I installed [leakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/) and got the trace above. After digging in the trace, from what I could understand it turns out I was keeping a reference inside fragment A to some views. Then when I was leaving from fragment A to the next fragment I was not clearing the views references correctly. So that was fixed by setting to null this references in the method onDestroyView() of fragment A.